# Android - how to add "quick scroller" to a ListActivity?

Tags: java, android, xml, listactivity

I'm looking to add a quick-scroller thingy that the user can drag down to quickly rummage through a large list. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android:fastScrollEnabled="true" in your listview